# Need a calender plug-in in Angular JS showing each 15 min data

Tags: jquery, angularjs

I'm working on migrating a Silverlight application to Angular JS(ANG1 as of now), I came to the below requirement to create a control like below.
I've all the backend data from REST Service.

[image]

It's divided into each hour every 15 minutes span, if I click on any of the block, it gives a pop-up of number of jobs ran in that timespan. Can you please suggest me how I can approach here? Any plg-in for this purpose?

Answer (score 0):

I think you don't need a plugin here, just code the whole thing with `ng-repeat` will do.

If your rest data fills in empty gaps for you (i.e. having the time block even when number is 0), then it should be easy, just loop over all data will do.

If it doesn't, then you'll have to generate the blocks yourself and then plug the data in the right blocks.